# No type mismatch - conversion from primitive int to boolean

Tags: java, decompiling

Consider the snippet from **CopyOnWriteArrayList**.

The return type of the method is **primitive boolean** whereas **primitive int** is being returned. The decompiler being used is-

> /*** Eclipse Class Decompiler plugin, copyright (c) 2016 Chen Chao
>   (cnfree2000@hotmail.com) ***/

```
public boolean add(E paramE) {
    ReentrantLock localReentrantLock = this.lock;
    localReentrantLock.lock();
    try {
        Object[] arrayOfObject1 = getArray();
        int i = arrayOfObject1.length;
        Object[] arrayOfObject2 = Arrays.copyOf(arrayOfObject1, i + 1);
        arrayOfObject2[i] = paramE;
        setArray(arrayOfObject2);
        int j = 1;

        return j;              // ?????????
    } finally {
        localReentrantLock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Is the **decompiler** the source of error as the code in selected lines is impossible to compile or is there some other cause for this?

If you look at the code [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.java), the lines are-

```
414     public boolean More ...add(E e) {
415         final ReentrantLock lock = this.lock;
416         lock.lock();
417         try {
418             Object[] elements = getArray();
419             int len = elements.length;
420             Object[] newElements = Arrays.copyOf(elements, len + 1);
421             newElements[len] = e;
422             setArray(newElements);
423             return true;
424         } finally {
425             lock.unlock();
426         }
427     }
```

which is perfectly in accordance with the expected.

Comment: Please post code as text, not images. You're wasting my mobile bandwidth.

Comment: And you won't get help from people on corporate networks that block imgur.com

Comment: @Aaron: Nice one.

Comment: @Aaron, thanks to think about us !! This look like you should change of decompiler

Comment: I wouldnt spend much time on this. When a tool that creates source code creates **invalid** source code, which part of the equation is most likely to be the culprit?!

Answer (score 3):

It looks like it is. Here's the following code decompiled with [Java Decompiler](http://jd.benow.ca/) (JRE 1.8.0_60).

```
public boolean add(E paramE)
{
  ReentrantLock localReentrantLock = this.lock;
  localReentrantLock.lock();
  try
  {
    Object[] arrayOfObject1 = getArray();
    int i = arrayOfObject1.length;
    Object[] arrayOfObject2 = Arrays.copyOf(arrayOfObject1, i + 1);
    arrayOfObject2[i] = paramE;
    setArray(arrayOfObject2);
    return true;
  }
  finally
  {
    localReentrantLock.unlock();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

From the [Java Virtual Machine Specification, section 2.3.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.3.4):

> Although the Java Virtual Machine defines a boolean type, it only provides very limited support for it. There are no Java Virtual Machine instructions solely dedicated to operations on boolean values. Instead, **expressions in the Java programming language that operate on boolean values are compiled to use values of the Java Virtual Machine int data type.**

So the decompiler is technically correct that the variable being returned is an int, at least at the bytecode level.

There is one exception: boolean arrays are not equivalent to int arrays:

> The Java Virtual Machine does directly support boolean arrays. [...] In Oracle’s Java Virtual Machine implementation, boolean arrays in the Java programming language are encoded as Java Virtual Machine byte arrays, using 8 bits per boolean element.

Answer (score 2):

Java has no instructions for handling booleans (except for accessing boolean arrays), they are implemented as ints with values 0 and 1.

```
boolean a = true;
boolean b = false;
```

is compiled into

```
iconst_1
istore_1
iconst_0
istore_2
```

The disassembler just got confused by this.
As a matter of fact all integral primitive types smaller than int are stored as int (this isn't a problem since Java widens smaller integral types to int anyway).